# two variable for loop gets caught in the inner loop

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to understand why my loop is not working as intended.

I am trying to write a loop that adds the numbers of each variable together according to their index row. So 20 + 20 = 40 [row 1 in both variables] and then 40 + 29 = 69 [row 2] etc. Instead, it appears to add each of the values in variable 2 to the first value in variable one, then all the values in variable 2 to the second value of variable two etc.

```
var1 <- c(20,40,60,80)
var2 <- c(20,29,33,34)


for (i in 1:length(var1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(var2)) {
    
    print(var1[i] + var2[j])
  

  }    
}
```

The output I get is:

```
[1] 40
[1] 49
[1] 53
[1] 54
[1] 60
[1] 69
[1] 73
[1] 74
[1] 80
[1] 89
[1] 93
[1] 94
[1] 100
[1] 109
[1] 113
[1] 114
```

What I want is:

```
[1] 40
[1] 69
[1] 93
[1] 114
```

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop iterates through all elements of var2 for each iteration of the outer loop, resulting in a combination of all pairs of elements from var1 and var2.

To achieve the desired output, you don't need nested loops. Instead, you can use a single loop to iterate over the indices of the variables and add the corresponding elements together.

```
    var1 <- c(20, 40, 60, 80)
var2 <- c(20, 29, 33, 34)

for (i in 1:length(var1)) {
  print(var1[i] + var2[i])
}
```

output:

```
[1] 40
[1] 69
[1] 93
[1] 114
```

Comment: Thanks - I should clarify that I was aware I could do it this way, but am now interested in seeing how i can break the second loop after it performs its first of its ith iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Using `purrr`:

```
var1 <- c(20,40,60,80)
var2 <- c(20,29,33,34)

purrr::map2(var1,var2, ~.x + .y) |> unlist()

[1]  40  69  93 114
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I worked out that has unnecessary steps but keeps the nested for loop:

```
var1 <- c(20,40,60,80)
var2 <- c(20,29,33,34)


for (i in 1:length(var1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(var2)) {
    
    if(j == i) {
      print(var1[i] + var2[j])
    }
    
    
  }    
}
```